# WPF Custom Control Font Properties

Tags: wpf, fonts, custom-controls

I have two custom controls one derived from ContentPresenter and the other one is derived form a StackPanel, of which neither have font properties. I now find that I need to implement font properties for these. I have tried implementing FrontFamily, FontWeigh and FontSize as dependency properties but they don't show up in the designer. Does anyone have and example of how to implement fonts in a custom control?

My code currently is:

```
    [ Category( "Text" ) ]
    public FontFamily FontFamily
    {
        get => (FontFamily)GetValue( FontFamilyProperty );
        set => SetValue( FontFamilyProperty, value );
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for FontFamily.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FontFamilyProperty =
        TextElement.FontFamilyProperty.AddOwner( typeof( MyControl ), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata( SystemFonts.MessageFontFamily, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits ) );

    [ Category( "Text" ) ]
    [ TypeConverter( typeof( FontSizeConverter ) ) ]
    public double FontSize
    {
        get => (double)GetValue( FontSizeProperty );
        set => SetValue( FontSizeProperty, value );
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for FontSize.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FontSizeProperty =
        TextElement.FontSizeProperty.AddOwner( typeof( MyControl ), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata( SystemFonts.MessageFontSize, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits ) );

    [ Category( "Text" ) ]
    public FontStretch FontStretch
    {
        get => (FontStretch)GetValue( FontStretchProperty );
        set => SetValue( FontStretchProperty, value );
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for FontStretch.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FontStretchProperty =
        TextElement.FontStretchProperty.AddOwner( typeof( MyControl ), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata( TextElement.FontStretchProperty.DefaultMetadata.DefaultValue, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits ) );

    [ Category( "Text" ) ]
    public FontStyle FontStyle
    {
        get => (FontStyle)GetValue( FontStyleProperty );
        set => SetValue( FontStyleProperty, value );
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for FontStyle.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FontStyleProperty = TextElement.FontStyleProperty.AddOwner( typeof( MyControl ), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata( SystemFonts.MessageFontStyle, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits ) );

    [ Category( "Text" ) ]
    public FontWeight FontWeight
    {
        get => (FontWeight)GetValue( FontWeightProperty );
        set => SetValue( FontWeightProperty, value );
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for FontWeight.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FontWeightProperty = TextElement.FontWeightProperty.AddOwner( typeof( MyControl ), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata( SystemFonts.MessageFontWeight, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits ) );
```

Comment: After adding the callback functions, the code appears to be OK. I can edit the properties in XAML editor, it just doesn't work in the designer.

Comment: Have you tried a different Category other than Text? I see a similar problem and it appears fine in the designer if I use Common, Appearance, or Miscellaneous as the category. The Text section UI may be special since it contains that tabbed control.

Comment: I put them in Appearance and they show as individual items. It would have been nice to have them in the text tab.

Comment: agreed. Microsoft has a forum for asking about issues and reporting bugs. You could ask there. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com